# PRJ file for Stereo70 S-42 projection?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, romania

I receive lots of Romanian maps with the projection STEREO70 with Datum "S-42 for ROMANIA". I have only found the "Stereo 1970.prj" by ESRI, and when I open the maps with my GIS software the coordinates do not match. As you can see, the PRJ by ESRI does not work with "S-42", but with "Dealul Piscului 1970":

`PROJCS["Stereo_70",GEOGCS["GCS_Dealul_Piscului_1970",DATUM["D_Dealul_Piscului_1970",SPHEROID["Krasovsky_1940",6378245.0,298.3]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Double_Stereographic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",500000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",25.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.99975],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",46.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0],AUTHORITY["EPSG",31700]]`

I don't know if anybody is working with Stereo70 + S42 projection and can share their PRJ.

Answer (score 2):

We (Esri) added the definition for ArcGIS 10.1. Here's the WKT:

PROJCS["Pulkovo_1942_Adj_58_Stereo_70",GEOGCS["GCS_Pulkovo_1942_Adj_1958",DATUM["D_Pulkovo_1942_Adj_1958",SPHEROID["Krasovsky_1940",6378245.0,298.3]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Double_Stereographic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",500000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",25.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.99975],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",46.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

and the "prj file" name it has: Pulkovo 1942 Adj 1958 Stereo 1970

[EPSG](http://www.epsg-registry.org/) now says that Dealul Piscului 1970 is an alias for S-42.

Answer (score 0):

If you export the PRJ given by GlobalMapper for Stereo70 and S-42 Romania, you get

```
Projection     STEREO70
Datum          S-42_ROMANIA
Zunits         NO
Units          METERS
Xshift         0.000000
Yshift         0.000000
Parameters
```

Of course, it's not a Well-Known-Text PRJ. But GlobalMapper does reproject maps between Stereo70+S42 and other projections.

Additionally, I've tried with the PRJ of EPSG=3844

```
PROJCS["Pulkovo 1942(58) / Stereo70",
    GEOGCS["Pulkovo 1942(58)",
        DATUM["Pulkovo 1942(58)",
            SPHEROID["Krassowsky 1940",6378245.0,298.3,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7024"]],
            TOWGS84[33.4,-146.6,-76.3,-0.359,-0.053,0.844,-0.17326243724756094],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6179"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.017453292519943295],
        AXIS["Geodetic latitude",NORTH],
        AXIS["Geodetic longitude",EAST],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4179"]],
    PROJECTION["Oblique Stereographic",
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9809"]],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",25.0],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",46.0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.99975],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000.0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",500000.0],
    UNIT["m",1.0],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3844"]]
```

but does not work.

Answer (score -2):

i the worse case... You can use an iOS application... to convert from Stereo70 to WGS84 
[iStereo70](https://itunes.apple.com/app/istereo70/id662608540?mt=8)

Comment: -1 since this doesn't include recommendations on which iOS application(s) can be used for the conversion.